# How to show all users in bash which does not end with "specific character"s

Tags: linux, bash

All the users in the `system` that dosen't have as an ending character on their names **a**, **s**, **t**, **r**, **m**, **z** must be shown in Bash.

The users names can be obtained from the `/etc/passwd` file, in the first column. But I can not perceive the correct approach to exclude those characters from the search.

Should I use grep? Or just a cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple one liner when using `bash`:

```sh
compgen -u | grep -v '[astrmz]$'
```

The `compgen -u` command will produce a list of users (without all of the extra fields present in `/etc/passwd`); `compgen` is a builtin in `bash` where it's normally used for username completion.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
grep -o '^[^:]*[^astrmz:]:' /etc/passwd | tr -d :
```

or

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep '[^astrmz]$'
```

`[^blah]` matches any character *but* the ones listed, the opposite of `[blah]`.

GNU `grep` using a *lookahead*:

```
grep -Po '^[^:]*[^astrmz:](?=:)' /etc/passwd
```

Or using `awk` instead:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /[^astrmz]$/ { print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Or in pure `bash` without external commands:

```
while IFS=: read -r name rest; do
  if [[ $name =~ [^astrmz]$ ]]; then
    echo "$name"
  fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

As you can see, there's lots of potential approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -vE 's$|t$|r$|m$|z$'
```

The cut command strips out the username from the password file.
Then grep -v (does the UNMATCHING)
     grep -E  does multiple matching (OR OR OR)
     the $ sign indicates the last character to match

For example , on my mac, I get:

```
_gamecontrollerd
_ondemand
_wwwproxy
_findmydevice
_ctkd
_applepay
_hidd
_analyticsd
_fpsd
_timed
_reportmemoryexception
```

(You see no names end with those 5 letters).

Good Luck.